# How many orbits are possible in the group action?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $G$ be the Galois group of a field with nine elements over its subfield with three elements.

Then what is the number of orbits for action of $G$ on the field with nine elements?

Comment: Ok. Can you tell us more about what kind of difficulties you have? Such as 1) How many elements are there in $G$? 2) What alternatives does that leave for the size of a single orbit? 3) What do we know about those elements that belong to the smallest possible orbits? 4) How many such elements are there? 5) What can you say about the rest? 6) How many orbits total?

Comment: Although there are abstract and general arguments that can handle it, this case is really totally computable by hand. You should write down the nine elements of the field, and see how the Galois group acts on them.

Comment: no of elements in G are 2 bacause it is degree 2 extension

Comment: as it is galois

Comment: further every automorphish fixes elements of subfield so 3 orbits i get

Comment: now furhter 6 elements left how to look for these?

Comment: OK, so there are two automorphisms. One of them is the identity, which fixes everything. So the other can't fix anything but the elements of the subfield. And, it has order two as an element of the Galois group. So that tells you what the other orbits look like, and lets you work out how many.

Comment: yes i got 6 orbits. 3 consist of single elements and 2 in each remaining 3

Comment: because no of elements in each orbit divide order of galois group

Comment: Good! Let me encourage you to write it up and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly the extension is of degree $2$ and as it is finite extension of finite field so is Galois (normal,seprable,finite). then Galois group consist of two elements
$G=(1,a)$ where $a$ is an automorphism of field with $9$ elements keeping base field fixed.

$\text{orbit}(x)=\{x,a(x)\}$ for any $x$ in $F=$ field with $9$ elements.

Now $a(x)=x$ for each element of the base field by definition as these automorphism fixes base field.

So we get $3$ orbits (separately for each element) with only one element.

Further we are left with $6$ elements of the field. Now further note that no of elements in any orbit will be $3$ defined above as they are defined in definition of orbit. Thus there will be $3$ orbits more with $2$ elements in each.

So in all there will be $6$ orbits.